# When to use "form" and when "format"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Which is correct?

> Please submit your ideas in text form.
>
> Please submit your ideas in text format.

***Format*** looks like it's derived from ***form***, so what is the difference between these two words?

I consulted a dictionary, but the definitions look somewhat similar to me — both seem to refer to the way things are organised / configured / presented.

I'm not asking for writing advice or suggestions to rephrase or substitute words, I'm simply curious about the difference between the two words.

Comment: Do you mean 'Word format', as in the software program published by Microsoft?

Comment: @JohnFeltz I meant the use of actual words, instead of pictures / audios etc.

Comment: If it's *not* a miswritten/mistranscribed reference to *MS-Word*, I suggest it should be *...in **text** form* (where ***format*** would be "acceptable", but significantly less common).

Comment: Seeing your comment, I'd say "in written form".

Comment: - well, [here's how things stacked up](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=text+form%2Ctext+format&year_start=1800&year_end=1990&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctext%20form%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctext%20format%3B%2Cc0) before ***format*** took off in relation to *computer data file formats*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks. I have changed the question to avoid misunderstanding  and better choice of words.

Comment: It looks rather like a "writing advice" question to me, but @John's advice is sound. You'll find hundreds of written instances of *[submit, set out, whatever] [**your ideas in written form***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22your+ideas+in+written+form%22), in Google Books, but few if any for either of your original suggestions.

Comment: What the difference is should be answered by a dictionary or two, though. Could you add your research into the question (so others don't repeat it) along with where there are still deficiencies in explaining the difference?

Comment: What about saying "Please submit your ideas in writing"?

Comment: @bookmanu: Nailed it! But I think that really just proves it's a "writing advice" question! Nothing to do with ***form*** vs ***format***.

Comment: Do you mean something like: Please submit your ideas in written form (describing the media to use), in plain-text format (describing the style)?

Comment: I'm actually really just curious about the difference between the two words, for the sake of knowledge. Right now, I don't know if they are synonyms, or under what context ***form*** or ***format*** should be used.

Comment: It's all pointless. If you or your interlocutor see a difference among "… in text form" or  "… in text format" or just "as text" then please explain it. Otherwise, why is this more than a simple question of choice or style?

Answer (score 1):

Both *form* and *format* have a wide range of meanings, some, but not all, having uses specific to computer files and documents.

Something in writing is not necessarily in “text” format. It may be handwritten (perhaps even cursive!). It may be in plain text or HTML, or MS Word. It matters if you have to put together contributions from several people.

One specific use of *format* is a file extension that indicates how a computer file is structured and therefore what applications will be able to view and, perhaps even more important, edit it.

Form, as another answer says, is more general. “The female body has a pleasing form”—-but no format that I know of.

Here’s Macmillan’s short list of “format” definitions:

noun

▸the arrangement, design, or organization of something

▸the size, shape, and appearance of a book, magazine, or newspaper

▸the form that a movie, television program, music recording, etc. is produced in

▸the structure and design of a written document, especially a computer file, for example the size and type of the letters and the width of the written area of the page

▸the way that information is arranged and organized on a computer disk

verb

▸to prepare a computer disk so that information can be stored on it

▸to arrange written material into a particular format, especially in a computer file

Provided by Macmillan Dictionary

[enter link description here](https://www.onelook.com/?w=format&ls=a)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion format is a part/mode of presentation of a form. For example the application 'forms' for different entrance exams and job applications contains descriptions in word format and  information regarding schooling details or qualifications etc. are in a specific table 'format'.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Because we expect answers to contain linked referrences to authoritative sources, not opinions; what you've written here would have been better suited to being a comment, you will be able to leave those on other's posts as soon as you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score -3):

'Form' has a general reference than 'format.' That said, I should add that format means the extension, ie: Pdf, ogg, MP4, doc, exe, etc. But 'form' constitutes the whole part of the file being presented in a particular manner. Form is the difference between a spreadsheet and a word document, but they both can have the same 'format:' pdf.
It's commonsense.

Comment: Your assertion that *form* refers to the file extension lacks support.

Comment: Actually he doesn’t say that.